# Session variable gets destroyed/nulled after UpdatePanel refreshes

Tags: asp.net, session, updatepanel, session-variables

I have a button inside an Update Panel and the button added as a trigger. On the click event of the button, a session is assigned:

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Session["Groupname"] = "aaa";
       UpdatePanel2.Update();
}
```

However after the update panel's refresh, I'm printing the session variable outside the Update panel just to test whether it's still available. To my surprise, it's now null and does not contain the assigned value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "after the update panel's refresh" do you mean in a separate postback event or the same one? Because, you know, things like page load event happen *before* button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm printing the session variable outside the Update panel just to test
>   whether it's still available.

you cant. you have to print the value inside the update panel. its how update panels work.

Comment: Ah thats the problem I need to get around. I need to assign a session variable inside the update panel and have access to that session outside the panel. But as it seems, the session becomes null when I try to print it outside. Whats the alternative?

Comment: can you post a more complete example showing where controls are?